# XSL: How to use HTML tags inside stylesheet?

Tags: html, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I got this code in my `XSL` stylesheet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="report:column-names/report:column">
    <fo:table-cell display-align="center" font-size="9pt">
        <fo:block font-family="{$font.family}" font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /> <--problematic value
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In the problematic value that I mentioned, I got values that I want to wrap with `bdi` html tag.

I tried to just put `bdi` and I didn't see my value, like this:

```
<bdi><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></bdi>
```

How can apply this tag for my values?

Comment: Can you provide the source xml (part) you are processing? The Xsl looks okay, so I'd rather suspect the `for-each select` is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? I need to know how to combine with my `xsl` and `bdi` tag

Comment: could you please write it as an answer ?

Comment: If the target format is XSL-FO then the result document should be valid XSL-FO. It is not clear what you expect to achieve by mixing XSL-FO with HTML5.

Comment: Can you show the XML for a sample `report:column` element?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix HTML and XSL-FO. XSL-FO is an XML vocabulary that is defined for formatting. The original purpose of XSLT was to transform arbitrary XML vocabularies (the 'X' in 'XML' comes from 'Extensible', after all) into the standard formatting vocabulary.  That's what you've been doing with the XSLT in your question.

The description of Unicode BIDI Processing in XSL 1.1 is at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e4879.  The applicable FO is `fo:bidi-override` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_bidi-override), and the applicable properties are `direction` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#direction) and `unicode-bidi` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#unicode-bidi).

You so far haven't shown the content of a `report:column` element, but it looks like you want:

```
<fo:bidi-override unicode-bidi="embed" direction="rtl">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</fo:bidi-override>
```

Without seeing a `report:column` element, the `embed` and `rtl` are just guesses.

(Using `disable-output-escaping` is seldom a good idea, but we can't see how bad an idea it is in this case without seeing a `report:column` element that needs it.)